# Writing on MSB o 16 reg

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have an `int` and I want to write its value to the most significant 8 bits. For example, the value 89 should become `10110010 00000000`

This is how I do it:

```
valueToWrite = myVal << 8 | valuetToWrite & 0xf;
```

How can I read back the original value?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I was thinking on signed but writing unsigned. The post post is changed

Comment: Why are you doing `& 0xf`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to read back the original value after left shifting (`<<`), simply right shift the value back.

```
myVal = valueToWrite >>> 8;
```

The `>>>` operator shifts the value right and passes zeros into the most significant bits.

Comment: Hm... very strange... i have written value 156 from bit 8 to 15. When I try your sample the returned value is 16 777 116.

Comment: I suspect that the method you describe in your question for creating `valueToWrite` is not very accurate. First of all, you appear to have left shifted 89 a total of 9 places, not 8, and you have an interesting recursion in the second term of the bitwise or. What exactly have you tried? [Here](https://gist.github.com/c139d1b19d0ccad3335a918bae344d3c) is a demonstration of what I'm talking about.